# On a "zero-mean" rational matrix-valued function

Tags: integration, matrices, complex-analysis, rational-functions

Let $F(z)$ be an $n\times m$ ($n\ge m$) rational matrix-valued function such that the column rank of $F(z)$ is full a.e. in $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex constant $m\times n$ matrices. Further suppose that:

1. $F(z)$ is element-wisely bounded and analytic on the complement of the unit disk in the complex plane.
2. $\lim_{z\to \infty}XF(z)$ is lower-triangular with (strictly) positive entries on the diagonal and $\lim_{z\to \infty}YF(z)$ is lower-triangular with real entries on the diagonal.

> **Question:** Does the following condition
>   $$
> \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(YF(e^{i\theta}))(XF(e^{i\theta}))^{-1} \mathrm{d} \theta = 0 
> $$
>   imply that $Y=0$?

---

**A simple remark.** If $n=m$ it is easy to see that the above condition implies $YX^{-1} = 0$, which yields the thesis.

Comment: It looks to me like it places restrictions on $X$, not $Y$. By (1) the elements of $F(1/z)$ are analytic inside the unit disk. And note that your integral is around the unit circle, which remains the unit circle under the transformation $z \mapsto 1/z$. Both $YF(1/z)$ and $XF(1/z)$ have no singularities in the disk, so the only possible singularities are from the inversion of $XF(1/z)$. But this can be expressed at the adjoint matrix divided by the determinant. The adjoint matrix is polynomial in the elements of $XF(1/z)$,  so it introduces no new singularities. (cont)

Comment: (cont). So the singularities of $YF(1/z)(XF(1/z))^{-1}$ in the disk occur at the zeros of $\det(XF(-1/z))$. Hence what your integral tells you that $XF(z)$ either has no zeros outstide the unit circle, or else that the zeros outside are balanced in their impact. Since $Y$ is independent of $X$, this says nothing about it.